# UIScrollViewの上にUITabBarを配置して、常に画面最下部にUITabBarを表示し続ける方法

Tags: swift, xcode

XCodeまたはSwiftで、UIScrollViewを配置して、その上にUITabBarを配置し、画面の最下部に表示し続ける場合、どうしたら良いでしょうか？
Constraintをする場合、どのViewにどのような数値でConstraintすれば良いのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Viewの下から0の距離でConstraintすると、画面から見切れた状態になってしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

iOSのYouTube公式アプリのように、常に画面の見える位置にUITabBarを配置したいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: UITabBarControllerを使った方がいいと思われるのですが、どうでしょうか？　参考：https://program-life.com/1008

Comment: ありがとうございます。個人的にはできればUITabBarで実装したいのですが、UITabBarControllerの方も参考にさせていただきます。